# Access model-specific constants in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

I'm running Rails 4.

I have a model called `Challenge`, and in my database I'm storing the `status` of each challenge in terms of 0-4.

But 0-4 isn't very semantic so I want to define a few variables (I'm assuming a constants) so that in any controller or view I can access the number by calling the constant:

```
# Challenge.rb
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  SUGGESTED = 0
  APPROVED = 1
  OPEN = 2
  VOTING = 3
  CLOSED = 4
end
```

I want to access these in my view:

```
# challenge/_details.html.erb
<% if @challenge.status == CLOSED %>
  Challenge is closed, broheim!
<% end %>
```

But my view doesn't want to render.

```
uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::CLOSED
```

What's the best way to set my status variables so that they may be accessed everywhere I need them? (i.e, anywhere the `@challenge` variable is present)

Comment: I recommend you to use a Hash as a Constant in this case. Why? Because it will reduce the number of different constants of your model. Something like: `STATUSES = { suggested: 0, approved: 1, open: 2, etc: .. }` and access to it like `Challenge::STATUSES.approved`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You should access them as following:

```
Challenge::CLOSED
```

Since your `CLOSED` constant is defined within a class, you need to access the constant using the scope resolution operator.  So if your view you would check it like:

```
# challenge/_details.html.erb
<% if @challenge.status == Challenge::CLOSED %>
  Challenge is closed, broheim!
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's a bit redundant considering my if statement is already referencing the @challenge variable. Is there a way to do it that's so semantic it reads like english?

Answer (score 9):

It's a really bad idea to code this kind of statements: your object must handle it's own logic.
Imagine if someday you decide to merge status, would you change every conditional in your codebase? No, you should use one method which handles the logic.

I'd do the following:

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  SUGGESTED = 0
  APPROVED = 1
  OPEN = 2
  VOTING = 3
  CLOSED = 4

  #defines:
  # - suggested?
  # - approved?
  # - ...
  %w(suggested approved open voting closed).each do |state|
    define_method "#{state}?" do
      status == self.class.const_get(state.upcase)
    end
  end

  #if you prefer clarity, define each method:

  def suggested?
    status == SUGGESTED
  end

  #etc...
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% if @challenge.closed? %>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem very semantic. It's also quite a confusing amount of code to have in the model of an open source project. Maybe you could elaborate on why @MrYoshiji's idea is so very bad?

Comment: Not a big deal to create methods if they make sense, much better than put internal logic outside of the model. @MrYoshiji idea is fine by the way.

Comment: btw, how could it be more semantic than `@challenge.closed?` ?

Comment: As far as semantics I was referring to the code implementation. I want people to look at the challenge model and understand every part of it, your idea just has too much cognitive overhead in comparison to @MrYoshiji's, but I appreciate the response!

Comment: I insist but it's a very bad idea to spread your model's logic outside of it's class it's contrary to OOP basics..

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to using enums, which introduced in Rails 4.1 if you're asking for enumeration of specific values.

```ruby
class Challenge < ActiveRecord
  enum status: {
    suggested: 0
    approved: 1
    open: 2
    voting: 3
    closed: 4
  }
end
```

After that, you can use these methods:

```ruby
Challenge.first.suggested? # For checking
Challange.first.open! # For change the status
Challange.open # Get all challanges with "open" status
```

For using enums, you have to declare an integer column with enum name (i.e: “status”) in your "challenges" (or which table related with model) table.

[For more information about enums](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#enums)